# Splitting Data and saving it a text document

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I have a text document [text_input](http://limelinx.com/flgt9)
And I would like to split the two values in the text, into two separate text documents using python.
                                                                            .

Thank you so much for all the effort you guys go to to help each other out!

Answer (score 2):

this should do it:

```
>>> with open('input.txt') as f1,open('output1.txt','w') as f2,open('output2.txt','w') as f3:
...     for line in f1:             #read data line by line
...         lin=line.split()        #split the line into ['19490622','14.0'] 
...         f2.write(lin[0]+'\n')   #write first part to output1
...         f3.write(lin[1]+'\n')   #write second part to output2
```